# How do I print a file exactly as it is shown?

Tags: python

I have a file that has this content:

```
dufhadqlhylwzl
xcqniythfkgwqw
ybzrfvkowgmvag
lalvggzvmhgaha
uluyopcpfgayeo
ejemtipntmbeaw
huqrhcumxtxcin
vnrykbsftbgtqq
aofxxszwtktazk
vgnitnuhtszzto
lonthkmfkakpus
dgznqjtzalxgvs
milyjorkjsgvtd

hunting
```

I want it to appear on my output exactly the way above, however, it shows up like this:

```
['dufhadqlhylwzl\n', 'xcqniythfkgwqw\n', 'ybzrfvkowgmvag\n', 'lalvggzvmhgaha\n', 'uluyopcpfgayeo\n', 'ejemtipntmbeaw\n', 'huqrhcumxtxcin\n', 'vnrykbsftbgtqq\n', 'aofxxszwtktazk\n', 'vgnitnuhtszzto\n', 'lonthkmfkakpus\n', 'dgznqjtzalxgvs\n', 'milyjorkjsgvtd\n', '\n', 'hunting\n']
```

So, what I want is to remove all '\n', and [] so it shows up exactly how it is on my file.
My current code is:

```
file = open(filename, 'r').readlines()
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        blank = line.split()
    print(file)
```

What do I change in the code to make the output exactly as it shows in my file?

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't do anything. It changes the variable`line` but then doesn't do anything with the variable. Each variable is just overwritten on the next loop so that the final instance of the variables, post-loop, are just the last tine stripped of `/n` and split. You could just remove the `for` loop entirely and it would change nothing about your code. For a next step, put `print(line)` after your `line = line.strip("\n")` and rerun. Ultimately this feels like an [xy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I'm surprised this prints anything at all, since you've already exhausted `file` in you `for` loop.  P.S. don't use `file` as a variable name.

Comment: @MarkRansom `file` is a list of strings

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer made by @OneCricketeer is correct and is probably the most efficient.  However, if you want it to become a list before printing out each line, you can do this:

```py
file = open(filename, 'r').read().split("\n")
```

Then, if you want to print out each line of the file separated by a newline:

```py
file = open(filename, 'r').read().split("\n")
print('\n'.join(file))
```

Or if you want the content of your file separated by a space:

```py
file = open(filename, 'r').read().split("\n")
print(' '.join(file))
```

Replacing what's before the `.join(file)` will change how the lines of your file are printed.  Changing what's inside the `.split()` will change how the lines of your file are read and separated into a list.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a for loop? You can `print(open(filename).read())` to get the file contents *exactly*

Otherwise, if you want to iterate over the lines, then you shouldn't strip or split them

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```